# Unity Ultimate Mobile Pro, как реализовать покупку?

Tags: unity3d, ads

Кто нибудь пользуется для Unity плагином Ultimate Mobile Pro?
Не могу понять как сейчас реализовать покупку.
Раньше до обновление использовал следующим образом:
Создавал скрипт

```
ublic class NoAds : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Start()
    {
        // конект, соединение
        if (!UM_InAppPurchaseManager.Client.IsConnected)
            UM_InAppPurchaseManager.Client.Connect();
    }



    void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
        // записывается событие до того как купить
        UM_InAppPurchaseManager.Client.OnPurchaseFinished += OnPurchaseFlowFinishedAction;
        // покупка
        UM_InAppPurchaseManager.instance.Purchase("crossads");
    }

    // проверяет купили ли мы товар
    private void OnPurchaseFlowFinishedAction (UM_PurchaseResult result) {
        UM_InAppPurchaseManager.Client.OnPurchaseFinished -= OnPurchaseFlowFinishedAction;
        //Если успешная покупка
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            // записываем в PlayerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("No ads", "yes");
            // удаляем кнопку
            Destroy (gameObject);
        } else  {
            UM_ExampleStatusBar.text = "Product " + result.product.id + " purchase Failed";
        }
    }

}
```

Затем перетаскивал на кнопку, и при нажатии на кнопку совершалось покупки и удалялась кнопка, сейчас после обновление `Ultimate Mobile Pro`, такой способ не работает

Comment: раз уж используешь про-версию может стоит обратится в саппорт разработчика плагина?

Comment: Писал, не ответили